# Functions returning various data types

Tags: php, function

In CakePHP there is a (quite fundamental) method called [find](http://book.cakephp.org/view/449/find). Most of the time this method would return an array but if you pass `count` as the first parameter the method would return a different data type - an integer.

The method is allowed to return various data types.

Isn't that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting languages tend to use this pattern of returning multiple types depending on either type of input parameters or value of parameters.

It can be confusing, but as long as you have good documentation its not a problem and can be very powerful.

Strongly typed languages use function overloads to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is a flexible way. In php standard functions return different types too. For example `strpos()`. It can return `integer` position and `boolean` false.

Comment: Alexander, strpos probably isnt a good example since the fact that it returns an integer or false is a problem since false == 0 is true but false === 0 is false, when first letter of a string matches this can cause problems.  However as a general rule in scripting languages returning multiple types is accepted behaviour

Comment: Just because the built-ins do it doesn't make it right.  The PHP built-ins do lots of things I think of as stupid.

Comment: @Toby, how about returning -1?

Comment: In my opinion returning -1 in this instance would have been a much better idea.  However I do feel returning more than one type from a function is valid in scripting language particuarily since they dont have a type system to specify the return type of a function.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. PHP is dynamically typed language, so you cannot guard yourself against functions that return various data types (unlike Java, where you can be sure what the function is returning).
That's very flexible (but also can be bad) so it's a good idea to guard against unexpected results by writing unit tests.
[You can see phpunit for a Unit Testing framework.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/)

Comment: I didn't know Java was a dynamically typed language... o.O Python would have been a better example, or at least JavaScript.

Comment: You should read better.
"so you cannot guard yourself against that (as in Java - where you can guard yourself against that because java is not dynamically typed")

Comment: I think the proper wording would have been "unlike Java" :)

Comment: I agree with you :) Will change my answer to sound more correctly

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad thing **as long as the behaviour is documented**. In C/C++ per example, which is a strongly-typed language, you can achieve a similar result by using void pointers (`void*`):

```
// returns a "const char*" if c == 0
// returns a "string*" if c == 1
const void* foo(int c) {
    const void* a;
    if (c == 0) {
        a = (const void*)"foo";
    } else if (c == 1) {
        string* b = new string("bar");
        a = (const void*)b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

You can then do this:

```
const char* x = (const char*)foo(0); // get a const char*
string* y = (string*)foo(1);         // get a string*
std::cout << x << *y;                // prints "foobar"
```

However, not documenting it properly **may result in unexpected behaviour**. Because if the pointer was to be cast as an unexpected type and then used:

```
string* y = (string*)foo(0);         // get a const char*, bad type cast
std::cout << *y;                     // Segmentation fault
```

The above compiles fine but fails at runtime. Of course, doing a similar thing in PHP will not segfault, but will most likely screw up the rest of your program.